How to upload JavaScript Blob to JSF without converting it to Base64 string?
I've recorded audio as blob in JS. How do I upload it without converting it to Base64 string and sending it via <p:remoteCommand> or <h:commandScript>?

Use a <h:inputFile> which is hidden by CSS and let the <h:commandScript> (or <p:remoteCommand>, whatever your preference is) process/execute it as well.
<h:form id="hiddenUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" styleClass="ui-helper-hidden">
    <h:inputFile id="file" value="#{bean.uploadedFile}" />
    <h:commandScript name="hiddenUploadCommand" action="#{bean.upload}" execute="@form" />
</h:form>

(note: ui-helper-hidden class is part of PrimeFaces, you're free to use your own)
In your JavaScript, you can use DataTransfer API to set the value of a <input type="file"> with a Blob. Provided that your audio blob is represented by the yourAudioBlob variable of type Blob, here's an example:
const dataTransfer = new DataTransfer(); 
dataTransfer.items.add(new File([ yourAudioBlob ], "yourFileName.mp3", { type: "audio/mpeg" }));
document.getElementById("hiddenUploadForm:file").files = dataTransfer.files;
hiddenUploadCommand();

In the bean, just bind the uploaded file to a Part property as usual.
private Part uploadedFile; // +getter+setter

public void upload() throws IOException {
    byte[] blob = uploadedFile.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
    // ...
}


after tries, I reached to: the request sent perfectly, the upload method in bean is invoked but the Part variable is null. so I'll ask new question.

It works for me in a completely blank project with the absolute minimum of configuration. Try the same so you can nail down the conflicting configuration.

I've no doubt that it's working. jsf-god's words are ultimate true. I agree with your suggestion for medium-size or well-documented existed projects-not the case I'm facing.

it works fine in new project.
